# Merge [nukes] and [nuclear-weapons]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Can we please merge [nukes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nukes) and [nuclear-weapons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuclear-weapons)? We really don't need both of them.

(I was going to just remove [nukes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nukes), but then I saw that it had more questions than [nuclear-weapons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuclear-weapons), so...)

Comment: Yeah nukes should be a synonym here +1.

Comment: Man, you really go through the tags.!!!

Comment: @KyloRen Yes, I do. :P

Comment: Awesome stuff. Keep doing it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Done.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/nuclear-weapons/synonyms)

Comment: I would have copied over the tag wiki from [tag:nukes], but it was a direct (attributed) copy-paste from Wikipedia. I'm sure someone can do better than that.